# Internationalization for constants-hashes in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3, constants

Could you tell me whats the best practice for storing constants with internationalization in rails3?

f.e. i want to have a constant-hash for haircolours for my user model:

```
# btw: how can I store such hashes in the locales.yml-files?
# en.yml
HAIR_COLOURS = { "brown" => 0, "white" => 1, "red" => 2, "dark-brown" => 3...}

# de.yml
HAIR_COLOURS = { "braun" => 0, "weiss" => 1, "rot" => 2, "dunkel-braun" => 3...}

# i18n.default_locale = :de
User.find(1).haircolour
=> 0
User.find(1).haircolour_str
=> "brown"

# i18n.default_locale = :de
User.find(1).haircolour
=> 0
User.find(1).haircolour_str
=> "braun"
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would suggest the following. Create a string column for the hair colour. This would normally be an enumeration column (`ENUM`), but this isn't supported by Rails unless you're okay with some SQL in your migrations.

In your model, restrict the colours to a few valid values.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Store the colours in the database as string identifiers (my preference
  # would be English, lower case, with underscores). Only accept known values.

  validates_inclusion_of :hair_colour, :in => %w{brown white red dark_brown}
end
```

Then, in `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
en:
  user:
    hair_colours:
      brown: brown
      white: white
      red: red
      dark_brown: dark brown
```

And in `config/locales/de.yml`:

```
de:
  user:
    hair_colours:
      brown: braun
      white: weiss
      red: rot
      dark_brown: dunkelbraun
```

In any view, you can do:

```
<%= t "user.hair_colours.#{@user.hair_colour}" %>
```

Or you can write a helper method in `app/helpers/users_helper.rb`:

```
def translated_hair_colour(user)
  t "user.hair_colours.#{user.hair_colour}"
end
```

Because I believe that translation is in principle a concern of the presentation, I would not create a method on the `User` model, but in principle there is nothing stopping you from doing:

```
class User
  # ...

  def hair_colour_name
    I18n.t "user.hair_colours.#{hair_colour}"
  end
end
```

---

**Update:**

Making select boxes in a view that are translated can be done in two ways. The **first option** is to use the translated values as a source. This requires the translations to be complete and accurate. If not all values are translated, the missing values will not be displayed in the select box.

```
<%= form_for @user do |user| %>
  <%= user.select :hair_colour, t("user.hair_colours").invert %>
  <%= user.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The **second option** is to use the validation values from your model. This is the "right" way, but it requires a slight adjustment to the setup of the validation.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  HAIR_COLOURS = %w{brown white red dark_brown}
  validates_inclusion_of :hair_colour, :in => HAIR_COLOURS
end
```

Now, in your views:

```
<%= form_for @user do |user| %>
  <%= user.select :hair_colour,
    User::HAIR_COLOURS.map { |c| [t("user.hair_colours.#{c}"), c] } %>
  <%= user.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, the mapping can be easily extracted into a helper.

Comment: Hmmm sound good..! Thanks! but is there maybe a even smarter solution? Will check this as answer if the bounty doesnt bring something better...!

Comment: Could you tell me how to make select_boxes with this solution? Will mark your answer as accepted if you answer... Thx!

Comment: @molf, I am liking this solution for mapping DB values to presentation values, even if I only have one language. One question: any thoughts on _sorting_ the select boxes? For hair color, you might want to sort by the translated value. For other items, you might want to sort by a fixed value, e.g. Account Type "Silver", "Gold", "Platinum" should always appear in that order. I wondered about adding a "_sortby" key to each locale's .yml file, e.g. account_types and account_types_sortby. But how do I get the view to sort the list based on the _sortby key?

Comment: @Mark, Displaying the items in a fixed order is easiest and straightforward if you pick the second option; e.g. use `Account::TYPES` as the array of account types, which would just be an array of strings: `["silver", "gold", "platinum"]`, and translate it with `t("account_types.#{type}")`.